# AWS and Wowza - Need to reinstall Wowza

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, wowza

So I have run into an issue, I use AWS and originally used their Marketplace Image for Wowza Standard. We then realized it would be cheaper to use the BYOL Version so that AWS only charges us for the Standard EC2 costs and not Wowza License as well. I was told by AWS support that I would need to terminate any server running the Standard Wowza AWS Image and spin up a new server using the BYOL Image.  I have roughly 34 servers, 20 of which I have been able to get recreated. The remaining 14 I didn't create and have no documentation from the previous tech as to how they where configured.

My question, can I spin up a new BYOL Instance, and then just copy the entire Wowza Folder over to the new server? Is everything contained in that directory that pertains to Wowza?

Comment: Seems like a better question for Wowza support than here.

Comment: So I found this [link](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?718-How-to-migrate-Wowza-Streaming-Engine-to-a-different-server), and it seems to be nearly that easy, can anyone confirm that I'm reading this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i prefer to copy only the following directory

**/conf**

Wowza Media Server configuration files and license keys

**/content**

Video on demand files

**/logs**

Wowza Media Server log files (if needed for your own billing purposes for clients)

**/lib**

Custom modules

**/transcoder/templates**

Transcoder AddOn templates

and install the wowza in the new instance replace the copied files , this will work and the important thing is wowza Licenses are associate with mechine id , so in this case your wowza will add 1 more additional instance for their license fee.

Comment: Ha, asked this question a while back, was having an unrelated issue with a wowza server, google searched for a solution and found my own post. >.<  For Shame... Oh well thats why we ask questions, so that others may learn from them as well.  In this case, it was me.   If anyone is having an issue where ${com.wowza.amazonaws.ec2.AWSEC2_METADATA_PUBLIC_IPV4} is not resolving automatically, don't forget the make sure the correct modules are in the lib folder.